# Standardizing AngularJS ES6 Class and file names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-class, es6-modules

I am working to give my Angular 1.5 apps an upgrade with ES6 classes and I've been following Todd Motto's styleguide pretty closely so far.  I have been naming component files like so:

```
    |-components/featurename
    |---featurename.index.js
    |---featurename.component.js
    |---featurename.controller.js
    |---featurename.service.js
    |---featurename.style.css
```

I have been naming classes like so:

```
const SomeComponent = {};
export default SomeComponent;
```

And then importing with the same name:

```
import SomeComponent from './featurename.component';
```

I'm wondering if dropping the featurename from all of this is going to cause problems with testing and debugging.  It would certainly make creating feature boiler plates easier without a generator.  I am proposing something like this:

```
    |-components/featurename
    |---index.js
    |---component.js
    etc..
```

```
const Component = {};
export default Component;

import Component from './component';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are free to orginize the sources in your project in a way you like to see them. The "featurename" prefix is useful for file-searching. I think this is the main point here. Let's imagine, we have 10 features, it means that we have 10 index.js files. Searching for "index" as a filename + "js" as an extension would give us 10+ results... in that case will have to search for feature specific folder. It may depends on the environment you are using for the development, there may be such a setup where it's not an issue.

Comment: fair enough regarding filenames, but what about class and module naming?

Comment: ES6 modules specification does not impose any restrictions related to what I see in your Post. Name your modules the way you think is better. If you have any real issue, you need to provide for example error log.